# Choppy/crackling audio

Tags: sound, alsa, hdmi, pipewire

Speakers make crackling and to a lesser extent, popping sounds when sound is played. Randomly, sound would completely cut out for 1 to 10 seconds, followed by much more crackling when audio returns. Eventually crackling returns to its lower 'average' rate, as if in that silent period, the computer is catching up on that time it wasn't crackling. Rarer than the audio cutting out, audio may echo. Sounds would repeat once, about half a second after the first sound (while still crackling).

Happens across a variety of software. Music via `mocp`, Youtube via `firefox`, and movies via `vlc` seem to exhibit the worst of this, with the last two occasionally showing audio to be slightly out of sync at random intervals.

Interestingly, if I try playing a game via `wine`, the audio is almost completely fine. I'd have to focus quite a bit to detect what little there is of the issue. It would be a single quiet crack every few minutes. However, the TV would randomly lose sound permanently (TV channels and other sources still work), which is fixed by turning the TV off and back on. This act of turning off and on would also randomly quit (or crash?) the game to desktop. When the sound is lost in this manner, it typically occurs after a single pop.

- Ubuntu 23.10.1 (default kernel and latest via `mainline` tried)
- Sapphire RX 7700 XT (default AMDGPU drivers and kisak PPA tried) Wayland and
- Xorg tried
- Two different TVs tried as monitors (older standard and newer smart)
- Two different HDMI cables tried
- All HDMI ports on the TV and video card tried
- Using `pipewire`, but `alsa` tried
- Under `alsa`, uncomment and edit `default-sample-rate` to `48000` from `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
- Under `alsa`, edit `load-module module-udev-detect` to `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0` from `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- All troubleshooting attempts tried one at a time then reverted to default